# Is it secure to use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie after validating login, then rely on AuthorizeAttribute only?

Tags: vb.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

We have a legacy system for which we are exposing a new web interface. It has its own authentication/login management system so I think we want to bypass a lot of what MVC4 can offer. We just need to have the legacy verify that a user and password represent a valid login, then find some means of ensuring that future requests aren't forged from another user/client. Can we accomplish this simply with:

Code in the controller that supports login:

```
Public Class HomeController
   Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

   Protected Overrides Sub OnAuthorization(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
      MyBase.OnAuthorization(filterContext)
      If Not User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
         ' Ensure that provided login parameters are valid
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(<Insert user name here>, False)
      End If
   End Sub
   Function Index(ByVal returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
      ViewData("ReturnUrl") = returnUrl
      Return View()
   End Function
End Class
```

Then I can simply apply `AuthorizeAttribute` to any controller function to make sure that it can only be called by an authorized user? For example:

```
' GET api/fsitem
<Authorize()> _
Public Function GetValues(<FromUri()> filter As IEnumerable(Of GridFilter)) As IEnumerable(Of FS_Item)
```

Is this adequately secure, assuming I tell the application what the value of `User.Identity.Name` is, or have I circumvented some important levels of security here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is basically using Forms Authentication cookie management without the Membership store.  This is a supported scenario for ASP.NET.  Here is an article explaining the difference between the two concepts.

[Membership is not Forms Auth](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/04/membership-is-not-the-same-as-forms-authentication/)

After the initial authentication, Authorize attribute will enforce the identity of the caller.  Not only this is adequate, this is the key security feature of the Forms Authentication.